# Не запускается nginx+php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php, centos

При попытке зайти на локалхост возникает ошибка 403 Forbidden.
Могу скинуть конфиги. Помогите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: index.php лежит там, где надо?)

Comment: Проверьте права доступа.

Comment: Вы имели ввиду index.html ? - он лежит по этому пути /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

Comment: Еще раз - проверьте права доступа (маска доступа+владелец+группа). Так же такой эффект может давать включенный SELinux.

Comment: права доступа на исполнительный файл:владелец - чтение и запись#
группа - тоько чтение
остальные - только чтение

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант вы могли менять секцию server, и изменили свойство root или же добавили директиву location и не правильно её сконфигурировали из-за чего она прикрывает вам доступ.

Выложи конфиг сервера nginx, если конечно проводились какие-то изменения. И посмотри в лог ошибок (error log), что там пишет.